# rotate mesh on page scroll in three.js

Tags: three.js, gsap

I'd like to rotate an object when the page scrolls, but I cant make it work properly.
What I have so far and updates the rotation of the object on page load is:

mesh.rotation.y = window.pageYOffset;

this however only updates the object on page load and not updating it further on scroll.
I know that for the camera you have to update the projection matrix to be able to have an interactive camera, on objects/meshes however this seems to be on by default (mesh.updateMatrix), I still cant make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

> I know that for the camera you have to update the projection matrix to be able to have an interactive camera,

I'm afraid this is not right. In many applications the projection matrix is actually static. A camera in `three.js` is a 3D object like a mesh. You can modify the `position` or `rotation` properties in order to transform it.

Check out the following live example that shows how to animate a cube on scroll via GSAP:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / ( window.innerHeight * 2 ), 0.1, 10);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 7);

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry();
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight * 2);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // gsap

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  gsap.to(mesh.rotation, {
    scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: "#trigger",
    start: "top top",
    end: "bottom top",
    scrub: true,
    toggleActions: "restart pause resume pause"
  },
    y: Math.PI
  });

}


function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
#trigger {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.122/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>  

<div id="trigger">

</div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with gsap, how would you do the same with vanilla js?  I'm guessing onscroll function and reuqestanimationframe?

Comment: I meant "you have to update projection matrix" for the normal persp camera - if you want to connect its movement to cursor hover for example, anyways, object is a different kind of animal

Comment: somehow this doesn't work with gltf, is there a way to do that, I read something about animationMixer but didn't work for me and there are few drawbacks that you have to keep it animating.

Is there a way we can conver gltf to Mesh so that it will work like what you showed?